# Why must the action be minimized?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

In mechanics, the only physical route a particle can take is the one where action is minimized. Why is this true? Is there a proof?

Comment: The principle of least action is a misnomer. The proper name is the principle of stationary action, because the action is not always minimized.

Comment: Whoops. Where does stationary action come from?

Comment: From the same place that any physical law comes from. Nobody knows why there are any physical laws at all.

Comment: That is untrue. Newton's second law is derived from this principle, as an example.

Comment: That is a *non sequitur*. There are equivalent mathematical formulations of various physical laws, but neither the Principle of Stationary Action nor Newton’s Second Law need to hold in the physical world for any *a priori* reason.

Comment: You are right. I suppose that by "law" you meant more of an axiom. However, Newton's Second Law is more of a theorem. I suppose Stationary action is more of an axiom.